# Javascript: having a number, with array push gives me NaN

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a really strange bug/problem... IE is giving me grief... and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong... IE in question is IE11...

so, basically I have a date string, the IE1 toLocaleDateString gives me (08/03/2017).... I need a string 8/3/2017 (how Chrome gives me fe)....so I am going long way, just to make sure I am doing everything properly...

```
    let date = new Date();
    let dateStr = date.toLocaleDateString();
    console.log("Date string:", dateStr);
    let splitChar = '/';
    let tokens = dateStr.split(splitChar);
    let result = [];

    for( let token of tokens){
        console.log('token', token);
        let t = token.replace(/\b(?:0*(0\.\d+)|0+)/g, '$1');
        let n;
        n = parseInt(t, 10);
        console.log('----- stripped', t);
        console.log('----- number', n);
        if(typeof n === 'number'){
            result.push(n);
            console.log('----- ARRAY', result.toString());
        }
    };
```

The LOG (IE11):

```
Date string: ‎08‎/‎03‎/‎2017
token ‎08‎
----- stripped ‎8‎
----- number NaN
----- ARRAY NaN
token ‎03‎
----- stripped ‎3‎
----- number NaN
----- ARRAY NaN,NaN
token ‎2017
----- stripped ‎2017
----- number NaN
----- ARRAY NaN,NaN,NaN
```

The LOG (Chrome 40)

```
Date string: 3/8/2017
token 3
----- stripped 3
----- number 3
----- ARRAY 3
token 8
----- stripped 8
----- number 8
----- ARRAY 3,8
token 2017
----- stripped 2017
----- number 2017
----- ARRAY 3,8,2017
```

So apart from IE and Chrome parsing the bloody month in different standard... (IE american and Chrome European)..

For some reason parseInt(t, 10) in IE(11) giving NaN... eventhough t is clearly a numeric string....

If I enter string myself... as in

```
let dateStr = ‎"08‎/‎03‎/‎2017";
```

It works in both browsers....

The only plausible reason I think is not working is because IE would not return actual number chars, but some other unicode char that looks like the number but is actually not

**EDIT =============================================**

I am checking the ascii code of the characters returned from **toLocaleDateString()**

and as suspected, IE doesn't give the actual normal chars:

```
let ascii = function(a) { return a.charCodeAt(0); }

let date = new Date();
let dateStr = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log("Date string", dateStr);
let splitChar = '/';
let tokens = dateStr.split(splitChar);
let result = [];

for( let token of tokens){
    console.log('token', token);
    let t = token.replace(/\b(?:0*(0\.\d+)|0+)/g, '$1');
    let n;
    n = parseInt(t, 10);
    console.log('----- stripped', t);
    console.log('charCode (t):', t.split('').map(ascii));
    console.log('----- number', n);
    if(typeof n === 'number'){
        result.push(n);
        console.log('----- ARRAY', result.toString());
    }
};
```

IE gives:

```
Date string ‎08‎/‎03‎/‎2017
token ‎08‎
----- stripped ‎8‎
charCode (t): 8206,56,8206
   "charCode (t):"
   [
      0: 8206,
      1: 56,
      2: 8206,
      length: 3
   ]

----- number NaN
----- ARRAY NaN
token ‎03‎
----- stripped ‎3‎
charCode (t): 8206,51,8206
   "charCode (t):"
   [
      0: 8206,
      1: 51,
      2: 8206,
      length: 3
   ]

----- number NaN
----- ARRAY NaN,NaN
token ‎2017
----- stripped ‎2017
charCode (t): 8206,50,48,49,55
   "charCode (t):"
   [
      0: 8206,
      1: 50,
      2: 48,
      3: 49,
      4: 55,
      length: 5
   ]

----- number NaN
----- ARRAY NaN,NaN,NaN
```

while Chromne gives normal ASCII codes:

```
Date string 3/8/2017
token 3
----- stripped 3
charCode (t): [51]
----- number 3
----- ARRAY 3
token 8
----- stripped 8
charCode (t): [56]
----- number 8
----- ARRAY 3,8
token 2017
----- stripped 2017
charCode (t): [50, 48, 49, 55]
----- number 2017
----- ARRAY 3,8,2017
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Do you really need to strip the token? I don't know about IE, but in Chrome parseInt('08',10) returns 8.

Comment: @AnaF: as I said... I went long route just to be 100% sure all is done correctly and I am not missing something... but as appended to the post, found the root of the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my appendix, it is an IE issue, that uses different unicode characters to represent a date string... so isNumeric or toInt are not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `Date` object using the constructor which can take each date part as a separate argument.

Comment: the problem is other way around ;) I have a date, need a string ;)

Comment: BUT, need a string that reflects locale settings... otherwise I could just use getMonth, getFullYear, etc...